# How can I arrange a Textview, in a Custom Listview Layout Adapter, placed beneath another Textview? Added adapter support

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I find my biggest issue when it comes to programming is placement sometimes, though these custom adapters can be tricky too. I know this is a confusing question so have prepared an image of what I would like to achieve.

[image: This is the current Layout I am working with.].

[image: And this is how I would like it to look like.]

So, what do you all think. Is there anything to be done here, or is this simply something I must do via string manipulation?I am using a horizontal, LinearLayout, and will post the layout file below. Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/steemlogoCURATIONROW"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/steemlogo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userDataCURATIONROW"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Poster Data:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/postDataCURATIONTOOL"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Post Data:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### Second Question!

Am I at all able to use multiple textviews within my Custom adapter? I am trying with just those 2 views right now, and it is giving me an error when I try the following code.

```
public class CustomCurationAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
public CustomCurationAdaptor(@NonNull Context context, String[] items1, String[] items2) {
    super(context, R.layout.curation_tool_row, items1, items2);
}
```

#### This returns the error:

```
"Cannot resolve method 'super(android.content.context, int, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String[]'"
```

Comment: Please, one topic per question. Otherwise it would be a mess or even likely your question would be closed (p.s. in short - yes, you can)

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to achieve this from my perspective is this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_text_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#99CCFF"
        android:text="First text row"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#CCFFCC"
        android:text="Second text row"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_text_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_text_view_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#FFCCFF"
        android:text="Third text row"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/ListItemTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#CC99CC"
        android:text="Fourth text row"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<style name="ListItemTextView">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
</style>
```

Thought it might be a bit heavy. For each row in list it use expensive operation of weightSum and double this calculation as it uses two LinearLayout inside of recycler view.

I would not optimize it before we really experience the issue on low level devices among device set team supports, but it would be good to look for most performance effective solution.

Might be constrain layout offer better options (anyway, percent layout was better alternative for this)

Comment: Love it when people actually awnser instead of quoting a rule! Thank you @Gleichmut